# Laravel variable naming

Tags: variables, laravel

When do I use a variable as 'name' and when as `$name`?

For instance when I declare the `fillables` in the model fine I go:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'title',
    'body',
    'published_at'
];
```

Here `$fillable` should really be a variable superficially, as it's a case for every single model there will normally be fillables. Yet it has the magic dollar sign.

Whereas the real variables `title`, `body` etc which change from one article (instance of the model) to another, they are enclosed between two apostrophes.

How do I tell the difference and when to use which?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case `$fillable` is a property of which ever model you are working on. `$fillable` is an array of table columns that you want to allowed to be submitted through forms to avoid [Mass Asignment](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#mass-assignment).

You would probably never deal with $fillable if you are new to laravel other then what you have already done.

To hopefully answer your question, here is how you might refer to your model.

```
$article = new Article();

$article->title = "new title";
$article->description = "new description";
$article->save();
```

You use the `$` to refer to a variable or object. You use the `$article->name` to refer to a property of the object.

Hope this helps.